# How to prevent to lose a theme modification in WordPress when the thme will update?

Tags: php, content-management-system, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have the following problem. I have to modify a JQuery function into a file named custom.js into the theme that I am using for my website.

I have no problem to implement my customization to the function but my doubt is: What will happen when the theme will be updated in the future?

I am pretty sure that the file will be overwrite and that I will lost my customization.

How can I prevent this situation and maintein my customization?

Comment: Copy the theme and create it as your own theme. But then you will have to workout any changes to the original theme and apply them to yours as and when you need to

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think that should exist some smarter way to do it !!!

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is forking the theme. Nothing complicated to deal with.

You should consider using a VCS like git or svn to monitor the changes you've made from the original theme, so you can apply them more easily to the latest released versions that the theme might have in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You're right! All changes made to the parent theme will be lost on updating. Nevertheless, it is not a good practice to mess with the parent theme / core WordPress files. You never know where one may go wrong.

WordPress recommends the use of [Child Themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) for modifying an existing theme.

Note that this method is easier compared to the Version Control mechanisms like git or SVN. Moreover you could keep track of all the changes made by you.

Now that you're using the child theme, its easier to dequeue the custom.js file included by your parent theme using the [wp_dequeue_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script) function. Then, use [wp_enqueue_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to enqueue the file in your child theme with the necessary customization made.